# iLO5 scripting to change SATA Controller Options

Tags: hp, automation, ilo

I want to change **SATA Controller Options** on **HP** servers with **iLO5**
How I can change it by scripting?
For example, I [found iLO4](https://community.hpe.com/t5/proliant-servers-ml-dl-sl/ilo-4-scripted-media-url/td-p/5665623/page/4) solutions, where people mounting virtual media by **iLO** scripting

```
cd /map1/oemhp_vm1/cddr1
set oemhp_image=file://var/images/isoimage.iso
set oemhp_boot=connect
```

In my case, I want to change **SATA Controller Options** (disable Embedded smart array and enable **SATA AHCI Support**), manually it's do like this:

**F9** on boot, than, System Configuration > RBSU > Storage Options > SATA Controller Options > Embedded SATA Configuration -> SATA AHCI Support

I found [iLO5 Scripting and Command Line Guide](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/a00018323en_us), but not found any links with this option (SATA Controller Options)

Can I do this by HP iLO cli or other (scripting) methods (not manual)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
By using [RedFish API](https://hewlettpackard.github.io/ilo-rest-api-docs/ilo5/#reading-bios-current-settings)
Thanks!